# Update an entire single column with table joined query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that I just added a column to and now I am trying to find an easy way to update it.

```
select * from KioskGoals kg
inner join [TestDB].dbo.Kiosks k on kg.kioskID = k.Id
```

The joined table has the names I need.  I want to update `KioskGoals` table and set the `kioskName` column = to the name returned from `[TestDB].dbo.Kiosks` which would be `k.name`

Is this possible with a single query?

The table that needs to be updated is `KioskGoals`.  The column that needs to be updated is `kioskName`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
UPDATE kg
 SET Kg.kioskName =  K.name
from KioskGoals kg inner join [TestDB].dbo.Kiosks k 
on kg.kioskID = k.Id
```